# AWS problem using HTTPS on C# server running on IIS

Tags: iis, amazon-ec2, https

I have a .NET core server on windows server with EC2 machine.
I want to have HTTPS access to my web app (used as server backend for REST requests).
My attempts so far were to enable HTTPS on the windows server machine IIS, choosing the only certificate which was there (WMSVC-SHA2), and open 443 in AWS EC2 security group.
However, no HTTPS requests are answered by the server.

what should I do? I am with AWS free tier for 1 year and trying to avoid paying for a certificate using ELB that accepts HTTPS and talk with the server with plain HTTP.

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is your server behind a load balancer, or are you using the same public address for HTTPS as you are for login (RDP)?  Connections disallowed by AWS will be dropped ( connection timeout after some time, no response will be sent).  The server could drop the packet(windows firewall?), reject ( not listening on 443?) or fail server side.  Which is it?

Comment: Even if you are short of budget, Let's Encrypt is free https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: @DanFarrell, no LB, same public address. why would a connection be disallowed if i added 0.0.0.. on port 443 in the security group?
the IIS server was configured to work with HTTPS (443) and i chose the certificate it offered me, which buffles me a bit, because how can IIS give me a free certificate that is known by a CA? to work with HTTPS to my knowledge you need a trusted certificated that is trusted by a known CA or else browsers will warn the user.

Comment: Also, when I send a request through POSTMAN I do not get a timeout but I get an immediate refusal "could not get any response", which hints this may be a configuration problem.

Comment: I would agree that if you can connect and get an immediate response ( be it success, failure, or connection error ) you're getting through to the instance.

Comment: @DanFarrell so what could it be then? the only thing i can think of which is a bit of an overkill is to check with wireshark on the instance.

Comment: @LexLi I'll check it out, though from what I see it mostly made for UNIX, so less info on windows, though i'm sure it's possible too.

Comment: Please ask Google, and see tons of guys use it for Windows.

Comment: Not google's fault windows knowledge is hard to share.  All those GUIs making things shockingly difficult to describe, if you ask me :P . Wireshark overkill?  It sounds like you're familiar with it and know how to use it.  Why not?  Other things, check open ports (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/netstat) , make sure you're actually listening.  Check IIS error logs.  Check app error logs.  Ask this question on Server Fault , which is where it should really be ( not a programming question).  Any or all might help.

Comment: great, thanks a lot mates!